# Input type Schema for dynamic fields

Tags: api, graphql, apollo-client

I've got an input schema type for my update mutation request but it only works when I send all fields mentioned in the input type.

```
extend type Mutation {
    createUser(payload: UserInput!): UserResult!
    updateUser(id: String!, payload: UpdateUserInput): UserResult!
    deleteUser(id: String!): UserResult!
}
```

```
input UpdateUserInput {
    id: ID,
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
    role: String,
    password: String
}
```

But I may need update only some of the fields there and if I am sending all of them they are sure thing are changed to the new input values.

```
        return {
            type: 'UserSuccess',
            code: 200,
            success: true,
            user: await this.update(id, { ...payload, password: hashSync(payload.password, HASH_ROUNDS) }),
            message: `User updated successfully`
        }
```

My request on FrontEnd part is:

```
mutation updateUser($id: String!, $payload: UpdateUserInput!) {
    updateUser(id: $id, payload: $payload) {
        __typename
        ... on UserSuccess {
            ...Response
            user {
                id
                first_name
                last_name
                email
                role
            }
        }
        ... on UserError {
            ...Response
        }
    }
}

fragment Response on Response {
    code
    success
    message
}
```

The Error I am getting is:

```
GraphQL error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
```

How can I make my Schema receive only some of the fields there? Because I cannot predict what fields will be updated by the user

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem not with my Schema but the way I was handling the request.
The error was coming from here:

```
return {
            type: 'UserSuccess',
            code: 200,
            success: true,
            user: await this.update(id, { ...payload, password: hashSync(payload.password, HASH_ROUNDS) }),
            message: `User updated successfully`
        }
```

To be more precise, here:

```
hashSync(payload.password, HASH_ROUNDS)
```

When I didn't send password it threw that error.
My bad!